# Github Pages with sveltekit only shows the HTML contents of app.html

Tags: svelte, github-pages, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit website deployed with Github Pages. All it shows is this:
[image]

The path is `https://username.github.io/src/index.html`. (I renamed app.html to index.html because routing to `https://username.github.io/src/app.html` didn't work for some reason).
Why is it not working? Is it because I renamed app.html to index.html? If that's the case then what should I do?

Comment: Read the docs https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages

Answer (score 1):

You have to *build* the application using the static adapter and then deploy those built files to the GH pages branch. See [these docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) for more info (note also the extra section on GH pages).